# Why is HashMap#get Returning an Object Rather than a String?

Tags: java, dictionary

This code prints `IS STRING` which means that that map value is a String.

```
if(mymap.get("name") instanceof String ) {
    System.out.print("IS STRING");
}
```

So why does `String newName = mymap.get("name");` throw the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String.`

This is what I used to initialize the map where `textName.getText()` is a string entered in a java swing GUI:

```
Map<String,String> mymap = new HashMap<String,String>(10);
mymap.put("name", textName.getText());
```

This is the relevant code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    Map<String,String> mymap = new HashMap<String,String>(10);
    mymap.put("name", textName.getText());

    makeDocx(mymap);
}

public static void makeDocx(Map mymap) {
    String newName = mymap.get("name");
    textReplace(oSelection, "[Name]", newName, oWord);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code around where you get the error (`String newName = mymap.get("name");`)?

Comment: I suspect that's *not* the same `mymap` variable...

Comment: doesnt make sense.. there is no error in there..

Comment: The code you posted seems to work fine. Could you post more of the code around the error?

Comment: The Map was declared in an actionlistener and the part that throws the error was used in another method as one of the method's arguments. Is that the problem? (new to java fyi)

Comment: Show both the code where you declare it and also how you reference it and use it.

Comment: @Cole can you just edit your question to include the whole method with the error (unless that's huge, in which case try to narrow it down)

Comment: Make sure you always declare `Map<String,String> mymap` and not `Map mymap`

Comment: `makeDocx(Map replacements)` --> You're using a raw type there, so `get()` will in fact return an `Object`. Also, do you actually call `makeDocx` with `replacements`? It doesn't seem to be defined at call time...

Comment: I think that is what i did! Thanks, i feel really dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this method:

```
public static void makeDocx(Map mymap) {
    String newName = mymap.get("name");
    textReplace(oSelection, "[Name]", newName, oWord);
}
```

The `replacements` is declared as a `Map`, which is the same as `Map<Object, Object>`. What you want is to change that to `Map<String, String>`:

```
public static void makeDocx(Map<String, String> mymap) {
    String newName = mymap.get("name");
    textReplace(oSelection, "[Name]", newName, oWord);
}
```

As a general rule, if you are using an object that uses Generics, but not declaring what types you are using, something is wrong. A good IDE, such as Eclipse or Netbeans, will put a warning under `Map replacements`, saying that you should add the types.

---

As a side note, you might wonder why you would want to do `Map<String, String> replacements`, rather than `Map replacements` with `String newName = (String) replacements.get("name");`. Imagine if you called the method `makeDocx`, but you passed it a `Map<String, Integer>` on accident. This will result in the program trying to cast an `Integer` to a `String`, which is impossible. And we like to avoid errors as much as we can, so we should make sure that we force the map to be a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: btw, i meant to replace "replacements" with "mymap" so fix that so the answer makes sense to others